# Clothes not working with armature

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

I'm trying to add some clothing to my charracter. Looked for some tutorials on yt, and it doesn't work. So, here's the mesh with clothing:

[image: Woman model with bikini]

Now, I parent panties to armature with empty groups and add modifier "data transfer":

[image: data transfer modifier]

But this happens:

[image: panties intersecting with mesh]

It definitely isn't perfect.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Did you try any of the other methods besides "Nearest Vertex" on the Data Transfer? I think you need to use an interpolated method.

Comment: Yes, I tried every option

Comment: You my need to model the clothes on to the model then. Since this is very low poly triangulation may be an issue.

Comment: Should I rather extrude clothes from mesh and keep it the same topology or in the same object create new topology

Answer (score 1):

OK, so all I did was to change a bit topology of model in spots where I wanted edges of clothes to be, next I selected faces on model and clicked shift+d and next right mouse button and separate by selection. I got new object, slightly alt+s it, solidyfy and change material. I got something like that:
[image]